# Rails 4.2.0 HABTM NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Having an issue with has_and_belongs_to_many on my models.

Here's the setup:

- Ruby - 2.2.0
- Rails - 4.2.0
- PostgreSQL - 9.4.4

I have the following models:

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
   # has_many :series_labels
   # has_many :labels, through: :series_labels
   has_and_belongs_to_many :labels
   has_many :videos
end

class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_many :series_labels
  # has_many :series, through: :series_labels
  has_and_belongs_to_many :series
end

class LabelSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :series
  belongs_to :label
end
```

I have the following migrations:

```
class CreateSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :series do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class AddColumnsToSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :series, :asset_type, :string
    add_column :series, :duration, :integer
    add_column :series, :external_id, :string
    add_column :series, :asset_created_at, :datetime
    add_column :series, :asset_updated_at, :datetime
    add_column :series, :asset_status, :string
    add_column :series, :asset_hosted_at, :string
    add_column :series, :original_file_name, :string
  end
end

class CreateLabels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :labels do |t|
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateLabelsSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :labels, :series do |t|
      t.index :label_id
      t.index :series_id
    end
  end
end
```

When I run rails c and supply the following:

```
s = Series.where(displayName: 'Some Series Name')
s.labels
```

I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `labels' for
>
> ## from /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in
>
> `method_missing'  from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in`
>   method_missing'  from (irb):2    from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`
>   start'   from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in
>   `console'     from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`
>   run_command!'    from
>   /Users/johnhenderson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:4:in`require'   from bin/rails:4:in
>   `'

Best I can tell everything is setup correctly, and there are values in all the tables in the database.

Thanks for any help,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Series.where(displayName: 'Some Series Name')` returns a collection of `Series` objects.  If you only want a single Series record, use either:

```
s = Series.where(displayName: 'Some Series Name').first
```

or

```
s = Series.find_by(displayName: 'Some Series Name')
```